# Cannot get values from XML files

Tags: c++, xml, omnet++

I have a problem with getting values from a XML file and work with the values in my .cc class.

I have a XML file that looks like that:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<heatSupplyLoadProfile>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 38.0160000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 50.6880000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 101.3760000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 114.0480000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 76.0320000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 63.3600000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 25.3440000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
<param> 12.6720000 </param>
</heatSupplyLoadProfile>
```

My DataCenter.cc class should work as follows.
I want to get each param and see if the param is greater than 0.0 if yes a message (DataCenterHeatMessage) should be created. Further a self-message should be sent.
The DataCenter.cc class looks like:

```html
#include "DataCenter.h"
namespace network {


Define_Module(DataCenter);

void DataCenter::initialize()
{
    //Get param XMLElectricity file from simple module
    heatSupplyLoadProfileArray = &par("heatSupplyLoadProfileArray");

    XMLElectricity = electrictySupplyLoadProfileArray->xmlValue();

        //Get values of the XML File
        for(childNodeHeat = XMLHeat->getFirstChildWithTag("heatSupplyLoadProfile"); childNodeElectricity; childNodeElectricity = XMLHeat->getNextSiblingWithTag("heatSupplyLoadProfile")){
            const char* valueHeat = childNodeHeat->getNodeValue();
            //Convert the node value from string to double
            heatSupplyLoadProfileArrayValue = atof(valueHeat);

            if(heatSupplyLoadProfileArrayValue > 0.0){

                DataCenterHeatMessage = new cMessage("heatSupplyLoadProfileArray");
                endTxEvent = new cMessage("send/endTx");
                scheduleAt(0, endTxEvent);
            }

        }
}

void DataCenter::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // Check if self message is received
    if(endTxEvent->isSelfMessage()){
        if(electricitySupplyLoadProfileArrayValue > 0.0){
            send(DataCenterHeatMessage, "outDataCenterHeat");
        }
    }
    else {
        throw cRuntimeError("self-message not delivered");
    }
}

};
```

DataCenter.h:

```
#ifndef __VISIONSIMULATIONOFPED_DATACENTER_H_    
#define __VISIONSIMULATIONOFPED_DATACENTER_H_   
#include <omnetpp.h> 
using namespace omnetpp; 
namespace network { 
  class DataCenter : public cSimpleModule {
    protected:
       virtual void initialize() override; 
       virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override; 
    private: 
       //state variables 
       double heatSupplyLoadProfileArrayValue;
       cXMLElement *XMLHeat; 
       cXMLElement *childNodeHeat; 
       cPar *heatSupplyLoadProfileArray; 
 }; 
}; //namespace #endif
```

Unfortunately, the message is not send to the module I declared.
I found out that this has something to do with the for loop. The for loop is not entered at all. If I comment out the lines belonging to get the values from the XML file, the simulation sends the message. Further, if I build the project no errors occur.

Could please someone help me with that issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show how `XMLHeat` is declared? Where this variable is set? How `DataCenter.ned` looks like?

Comment: Hi Jerzy, this is done in the simple module DataCenter. The code looks like this: `simple DataCenter
{
    parameters:
        @class(network::DataCenter); 
        volatile xml heatSupplyLoadProfileArray = xmldoc("heatSupplyLoadProfileWinter.xml");

    gates:
        output outDataCenterHeat;
}`

Comment: How `XMLHeat` is declared and when do you assign a value to `XMLHeat`?

Comment: This is done in the header file of the data center module with `cPar *heatSupplyLoadProfileArray`.

Comment: So could you present this header file? I cannot reproduce your error, and therefore it is difficult to help you. Take a look at: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sure, here it is with only variables used for XML:
`#ifndef __VISIONSIMULATIONOFPED_DATACENTER_H_
#define __VISIONSIMULATIONOFPED_DATACENTER_H_
#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;
namespace network {
class DataCenter : public cSimpleModule
{
    protected:
      virtual void initialize() override;
      virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
    private:
      //state variables
      double heatSupplyLoadProfileArrayValue;
      cXMLElement *XMLHeat;
      cXMLElement *childNodeHeat;  
      cPar *heatSupplyLoadProfileArray;
};
}; //namespace
#endif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that in `DataCenter.ned` there is the following declaration:

```
xml heatSupplyLoadProfileArray;
```

and `omnetpp.ini` contains:

```
**.heatSupplyLoadProfileArray = xmldoc("heat.xml")
```

where `heat.xml` is a file that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <heatSupplyLoadProfile>
  <param>   12.6720000  </param>
  <param>   76.0320000  </param>
  <param>   114.0480000 </param>
</heatSupplyLoadProfile>
```

To read data from this XML file one should use the following code:

```
cXMLElement *rootelement = par("heatSupplyLoadProfileArray");
cXMLElementList params= rootelement->getChildrenByTagName("param");
for (const auto & element : params) {
    const char* valueHeat = element->getNodeValue();
    float val = atof(valueHeat);
    EV << "Read value: " << val << std::endl;
    if (val > 0.0) {
       // send a message or self-message
    }
}
```